# Is it possible to group textboxes in WPF so that I can iterate through them?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Okay, let's say I have 15 textboxes in a window. I have a button in the window as well that that gets enabled using the ICommand interface. I want the CanExecute methed of the interface to return false if say  any of  a certain 5 of the 10 textboxes are blank. These 5 textboxes may not be grouped together in the window physically. Is there anyway to group these five textboxes together so that I don't have to iterate through each textbox in the window and use a bunch of if/else statements to see if they are blank? Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Use old good `x:Name` and then put them into a list.

Comment: Ok, I will try that. Just add them to a list in the class that implements ICommand?

Comment: You say `ICommand`. It's half-way till MVVM and then it's suddenly a simple binding of View textboxes to `ObservableCollection<string>` which you can iterate in view model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go with bindings

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Text1}" ... />
...
<TextBox Text="{Binding Text33}" ... />
```

ViewModel:

```
string[] _text = new string[33];
// repeat this 33 times
public string Text1
{
    get { return _text[0]; }
    set
    {
        _text[0] = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
        SomeCommand.Update(); // evaluate CanExecute
    }
}

SomeCommand = new DelegateCommand( ... , !_text.Any(o => o.IsNullOrEmpty()));
```

See [DelegateCommand](http://www.wpftutorial.net/delegatecommand.html).